# Unable to connect to external_link?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a generic DB which is running inside another network. I would like to be able to connect to the DB from my API. To do so I have tried to use external_links. However, when I connect to the DB from my API: `mysql -h db_1 -u user -p` I get this error: `ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db_1' (0)`

Here, is the docker-compose.yml for my app:

```
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    image: s2s/api:latest
    command: start
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    external_links:
      - db_1
```

Other, docker-compose.yml file containing my db:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
      image: mysql:5.7
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: name
        MYSQL_USER: user
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      ports:
        - 3306:3306
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not split container's definitions while using Docker Compose. Please use the following one:

```
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    image: s2s/api:latest
    command: start
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: name
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

In case you specifically need to split them for some reason, please use [networks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network-configuration-reference), as `external_links` are not recommended.